# I want to add a scroll and infinite scrolling to jQuery each command

Tags: php, jquery, xml, rss, rss-reader

The following code parses an rss feed from XML and displays it as a listview on a php/jquery page. Pretty cool so far with only only issue

```
 function parseXml(xml)
  {
    $("#main").html("<ul id='content' data-role='listview' data-inset='true'></ul>");

    //make window scrollable after items exceed document height
    $document_height = $(document).height();
    $culminated_height = 0;
    $items_displayed_on_screen = 0;

    $(xml).find("item").each(function()
    {

      $("#content").append("<li><a href='"+$(this).find("date").text()+"'><img src='"+$(this).find("location").text()+"'/><h2>"+$(this).find("report").text()+"</p></a></li>");

      //make scrollable after document height is reached
      $culminated_height  +=  $("li").height();

      $items_displayed_on_screen++;
      if ($culminated_height >= $document_height){



              return false; //break
          }

    });
```

I cant make this scrollable. So far the `$culminated_height` and `$document_height` help me to stop displaying more items when the culminated height exceeds the window/document height. I need this section to be scrollable that does not greatly exceed the window height and further content sort of auto loads as a user goes further down the scroll. I've looked into jquery infinite scrolling techniques but can't seem to make them work with this jQuery each function so far. Any help?

Comment: Are you opposed to a fixed height and overflow-y:scroll;?

Comment: Can you elaborate I'm not an expert on css. Whatever works really.
Edit: Okay I got the message let me try that.

Comment: If we want to use content for instance, `$('#content').css({'height' : '300px', 'overflow-y': 'scroll'});` See how that works for you.

Comment: Alright wow thanks that actually almost works as I intend it to. Two issues though, instead of a 300px height can I give the document height in this?

Also one of my aims is to 'lazy-load' content for efficiency as one scrolls down. Is that possible. But thanks this was really really helpful.

Comment: Okay so I used `height: 100vh` for the 100% height. The infinite scrolling 'lazy-load' for efficiency purposes is still an issue though.